# java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke and Spring @Async

Tags: multithreading, spring, asynchronous, reflection, java.util.concurrent

I have a scenario where a method needs to be invoked if it has a particular annotation. The method also needs to run in a separate thread so I used `@Async`, however, it is not run concurrently.

if `java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke` is not used and good old `Object.methodName()` is used, the method does run asynchronously.

Is there a limitation in such a scenario? I'm using JDK 1.7 and Spring 4.x.

I have the following in applicationContext.xml:
`<task:annotation-driven />`

The class (basically a listener/callback):

```
@Service
@BackgroundJob
public class ItemHold {
private XLogger logger = XLoggerFactory.getXLogger(ItemHoldAnnotation.class
        .getName());

@Async
private void doItemHoldCheck() {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(30 * 1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

@BackgroundJobCallback
public void mangoesTasteGood() {
    logger.error("...tick...");
    doItemHoldCheck();
}
}
```

The caller:

```
@Service
public class BatchServiceAnnotationImpl implements BatchService {

private XLogger logger = XLoggerFactory
        .getXLogger(BatchServiceAnnotationImpl.class.getName());

@Inject
ApplicationContext context;

Map<Object, Method> mJobMap = new HashMap<Object, Method>();

@Scheduled(cron = "0/5 * * * * ?")
public void timer() {
    performBatchJobs();

}

private void performBatchJobs() {
    for (Map.Entry<Object, Method> entry : mJobMap.entrySet()) {
        try {
            Object object = entry.getKey();
            Method method = entry.getValue();

            method.invoke(object, null);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new AppServiceException(
                    "Failed to perform Background Job", e);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            throw new AppServiceException(
                    "Failed to perform Background Job", e);
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            throw new AppServiceException(
                    "Failed to perform Background Job", e);
        }
    }
}

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    /*
     * Annotation based: Detect any Bean having BackgroundJob annotation.
     * Then find the method annotated with BackgroundJobCallback.
     */
    Map<String, Object> beans = context
            .getBeansWithAnnotation(BackgroundJob.class);
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : beans.entrySet()) {
        Object backgroundJob = entry.getValue();
        Class<?> clazz = backgroundJob.getClass();
        for (Method method : clazz.getDeclaredMethods()) {
            if (method.isAnnotationPresent(BackgroundJobCallback.class)) {
                mJobMap.put(backgroundJob, method);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Hope you enabled Async support using annotation @EnableAsync

Comment: Can you show some code where you are invoking the `@Async` method?  Are you aware of how Spring implements support for `@Async` (typically by using proxies)?  If you are using reflection on a proxy you can get weird results.

Comment: @JohnR I have updated the question with relevant code.

Comment: How are you obtaining the Method instance in the Map?

Comment: @JohnR, There is a method with `@PostConstruct`, I'm locating the bean and the method there. You will have to scroll down in `BatchServiceAnnotationImpl `

Comment: You have the `@Async` annotation on a private method.  That's not going to work unless you are using compile time or load time weaving with AspectJ.